# Autofac wait for module to become available

Tags: autofac

Because the order of modules being resolved is not guaranteed I'm having some problem achieving this:

I have a module which registers a `ScheduleService` this `ScheduleService` is responsible for trigger events at set intervals etc.

I'm able to load in different `IScheduable` items which i do so using the `XML Configuration`. The problem that i have, is the `IScheduable` items require the `IScheduleService` to be ready so it can register it's self.

So in my `<autofac><modules>` I have

```xml
<module type="Namespace.ScheduleServiceModule, Namespace" />
```

Then the idea was I could load in as many different `ISchedulable` items

```xml
<module type="SomeNamespace.ScheudleItem1, SomeNamespace />
<module type="SomeNamespace.ScheudleItem2, SomeNamespace />
<module type="SomeNamespace.ScheudleItem3, SomeNamespace />
<module type="SomeNamespace.ScheudleItem4, SomeNamespace />
```

This is currently how I do it in those scheduleitem modules:

```C#
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterCallback(registry =>
    {
        var scheduleService = new TypedService(typeof(IScheduleService)); 
        var registrations = registry.RegistrationsFor(scheduleService);
        if (registrations != null && registrations.Any())
        {
            IComponentRegistration componentRegistration = registrations.First();
            componentRegistration.Activated += (sender, args) =>
            {
                IScheduleService scheduleService = args.Instance as IScheduleService;
                if (scheduleService != null)
                {
                    OnScheduleServiceAvailable(args.Context, scheduleService);
                }
            };
        }
    });
    base.Load(builder);
}
```

This is the override in each of ScheduleItems

```C#
protected override void OnScheduleServiceAvailable(IComponentContext context,
                                                   IScheduleService scheduleService)
{
    scheduleService.Add(
        new SqlSyncSchedulable(Enabled, IntervalMS, ConnectionString, SqlSelect, 
            context.Resolve<ILoggerService>(), 
            context.Resolve<IPersonService>(), 
            context.Resolve<ILoggingEventService>(), 
            context.Resolve<ITemplateService>(), 
            context.Resolve<ITemplateLoggingEventService>(), 
            context.Resolve<IRuntimeSettingsService>()));
 }
```

Which is quite intermittent. The `ISchedule` item should register itself but the problem is the `Schedule` service might be registered after those items.

There must be a way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and share your `OnScheduleServiceAvailable` source code ?

Comment: Updated with the OnScheduleServiceAvailable

Comment: Aren't you able to use a dependencies on factories (`Func<IInterface>`) instead? That the dependency does not need to be available until it is requested. See [Delegate Factories](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html)

Comment: I'm not sure how you would acheive that from within a module? I don't have access to the container, unless i miss-understood them.

Comment: If you have a parameter of type `Func<IInterface>`, the `IInterface` service will only be instanciated when you call the method

Comment: I may misunderstand the question but why don't you use the `AttachToComponentRegistration` method of a module ? When a module is added to the container, *Autofac* will invoke this method for all current registrations and each time a new registration will be added

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not in the load order of the module, but is instead about dependency design.

You should design your modules and your dependencies in a way that they are not temporally coupled.

One of the many possible designs involves having the schedule service require a list of possible dependencies.

In this design, the responsibilitt of an `ISchedule` is in defining the parameters of a schedulable operation, you use Autofac `Adapter` pattern to wrap each schedule into a `ISyncSchedulable` operation, and the `ScheduleService` requires a `List<ISyncSchedulable>` in order to add them at initialization.

As an example (following your example, but not verbatim: I'm trying more to make a point than giving a complete solution):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Example
{
    public interface ISchedule
    {
        bool Enabled { get; }
        long IntervalMs { get; }
        string ConnectionString { get; }
        string SqlSelect { get; }
    }

    public class Schedule : ISchedule
    {
        public bool Enabled
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public long IntervalMs
        {
            get { return 100000; }
        }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return "localhost;blabla"; }
        }

        public string SqlSelect
        {
            get { return "select 1 as A"; }
        }
    }


    // let's assume SqlSyncSchedulable inherits from a common
    // ISyncSchedulable interface
    public interface ISyncSchedulable
    {
        void RunSchedule(ScheduleService scheduleService);
    }

    public class SqlSyncSchedulable : ISyncSchedulable
    {
        public ISchedule Schedule { get; private set; }
        public OtherService OtherService { get; private set; }

        public SqlSyncSchedulable(ISchedule schedule,
            OtherService otherService
            /*,ILoggerService loggerService
            IPersonService personService, */
        )
        {
            Schedule = schedule;
            OtherService = otherService;
            // read interval and other data from schedule,
            // store service references as usual.
        }

        public void RunSchedule(ScheduleService scheduleService)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class OtherService
    {

    }

    public class ScheduleService
    {
        public ScheduleService(IList<ISyncSchedulable> schedulables, OtherService otherService /*, ... other dependencies */)
        {
            // there is no ADD! Autofac gives you a list of all possible
            // ISyncSchedulable components
            SyncSchedulables = schedulables;
            // ... other dependencies
        }

        public IList<ISyncSchedulable> SyncSchedulables { get; set; }

        // this code is not a proper implementation, nor a scheduler,
        // it's just a placeholder
        public void RunSchedules()
        {
            foreach (var schedule in SyncSchedulables)
            {
                // do your operations, involving ...
                schedule.RunSchedule(this);
            }
        }
    }


    public class TestModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Load(builder);

            builder.RegisterType<ScheduleService>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<OtherService>().AsSelf();

            // don't worry about which type should be registered,
            // and register each type inheriting from ISchedule
            // coming from the current assembly
            // You can even use a single registration for all the
            // possible implementations of ISchedule, using techniques
            // explained in http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetType().Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ISchedule)))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerDependency();

            // This registration is a partial, because
            // SqlSyncChedulable requires a single parameter
            // of type ISchedule
            builder.RegisterType<SqlSyncSchedulable>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

            // for each ISchedule class, we register automatically
            // a corresponding ISyncSchedulable, which
            builder.RegisterAdapter<ISchedule, ISyncSchedulable>(RegisterISyncSchedulableForEachISchedule)
                .InstancePerDependency();
        }

        private ISyncSchedulable RegisterISyncSchedulableForEachISchedule(IComponentContext context, ISchedule schedule)
        {
            // the parameter of type ISchedule is the corresponding schedule
            var scheduleParam = new TypedParameter(typeof(ISchedule), schedule);
            // all the other params are resolved automatically by Autofac.
            return context.Resolve<ISyncSchedulable>(scheduleParam);
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class AutofacTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestServiceResolution()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule(new TestModule());
            var container = builder.Build();

            var service = container.Resolve<ScheduleService>();

            Assert.That(service.SyncSchedulables[0].GetType(), Is.EqualTo(typeof(SqlSyncSchedulable)));
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that the module resolution order is now completely decoupled with the runtime resolution.